# While Loop Initiates Index as 1?

Tags: php, mysqli

I'm trying to retrieve an SQL column as an array and loop through each entry individually for a dictionary-like display.

My issue is that every entry is displayed EXCEPT the first when I use the following code:

```
require("config.php");
if($conn){
    $select = "SELECT word FROM draft1";
    $displayQuery = mysqli_query($conn, $select);
    $wordsArray = mysqli_fetch_array($displayQuery);
    while($i = mysqli_fetch_array($displayQuery)){
        echo "<div>$i[word]</div>";
    }
    mysqli_close($conn);
}
```

If I had an array like `$displayQuery = ['One', 'Two', 'Three'];` what I would get is `Two Three`

I've tried initializing the `$i` variable as 0 then iterating, but that provides me with an undefined offset so I wonder if I'm not actually retrieving an array with `mysqli_fetch_array`?

Comment: You have `mysqli_fetch_array` twice, that advances the cursor for every call. Get rid of the first call. `$wordsArray = mysqli_fetch_array($displayQuery);`

Comment: As per @user3783243 your `$wordsArray = ... ` is not only pointless, it advances the "cursor" by 1 before your `while` loop executes. Maybe it's a relic when you were testing and was never removed.

Comment: If you want to avoid such simple mistakes use `foreach` instead of `while` loop.